# Do cheap triacs burn out more easily?

Tags: triac, current-limiting, high-current

I built a stick welder using two microwave transformers and a DC bridge rectifier. To control the heat, I created a triac current regulator attached to the AC input of the transformers. I have used this specific circuit for a long time with these transformers however I got an overheat blow out of my BTA41-600B triac last time (the triac physically caught fire). I ordered 4 new ones, and  they seem to be instantly failing with the load terminals stuck open. If I allow full current to pass through the triac, it doesnt break, however when I try to regulate the current, it instantly stops regulation and stays shorted. Is there something wrong with my design? And if so, why are these the only triacs being affected?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcap2f.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Counterfeit parts are common. Make sure you are purchasing from a reputable distributor.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the source?

Comment: http://www.ebay.com/itm/4pcs-STMicroelectronics-BTA41-600B-Triac-600V-40A/121500114411?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649

Comment: It doesn't seem that the seller is aware of any issues and offered a return.

Comment: I would not have believed it if I had not seen it with my own eyes, but the following listing item title actually appears on a usual suspects ecommerce site: **"BTA41-600B [absolutely original ic] fake a compensable special store diy electronic ic component"**

Answer (score 2):

These were most likely counterfeit, I ordered a new batch directly from the company and they worked perfectly.